# Find and display hidden div when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got a quick question here. I'm not sure if this is possible but.. I want to have a tooltip-ish function going on on my website. However, i want it to be kinda dynamic, so i don't have to have 100 unique divs.

If i have 4 divs, that looks the same, how would i go about just displayig the tooltip inside the div am hovering?

**Example**

```
<div id="theLink" class="123">
    <img src="images/icons/icon_pc.png" alt="">

    <div class="tooltip_websites">
          <div class="arrow_up"></div>
          <p>aiuwd hiau dhwuiaw diuah dwiauh dwaiuwd haiwudh</p>
    </div> <!-- end tooltip_websites -->
</div> <!-- end bullet-circle -->
```

what if i have 4 divs like that, and when i hover #thelink i wanna display the "tooltip_website" for that current div? and not displaying the  three others?

**Right now I'm using:**

```
$("#theLink").hover(
    function () {
        $(".tooltip_websites").stop(true).fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $(".tooltip_websites").stop(true).fadeOut();
});
```

But if i want it to be more dynamic, what could i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.find()` to only target the elements that lie within selected dom:

```
$("#theLink").hover(
function () {
    $(this).find(".tooltip_websites").stop(true).fadeIn();
},
function () {
     $(this).find(".tooltip_websites").stop(true).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`

```
$(".tooltip_websites",this).stop(true).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

*what if i have 4 divs like that,*

**IDs must be unique** use classes instead.

Change your HTML as

```
<div class="theLink" class="123">
```

JavaScript

```
$(".theLink").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find(".tooltip_websites").stop(true).fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find(".tooltip_websites").stop(true).fadeOut();
});
```